# Difference between "went through numerous" vs "went through the numerous"?

Tags: difference, definite-article

The full sentence was:

> He went through **the numerous** pavilions and buildings, bridges and corridors, before arriving at the training hall’s door.

What is the use of "the" before "numerous" in this sentence? Is it emphasizing something?

Edit: These buildings, pavilions, bridges and corridors haven't been mentioned before this sentence.

Comment: Using "the" would define an already mentioned set of "pavilions and buildings". Since you said that is not the case, don't use "the". It could be used for emphasis, but again there needs to be a defined set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "the" in this context is restricting our attention to a certain set of buildings, etc.  In this context, it's probably clear which buildings are referred to.  Let's say somewhere previously, he had just arrived in Paris and that arrival is the subject of discussion.  While the reader is thinking about Paris, you can say "he walked across the numerous bridges."  The reader knows which bridges these are, at least generally.  Writing it this way focuses the reader's attention on the nature of the location.

Omitting the article indicates that the reader, and perhaps the writer, doesn't know which bridges and pavilions were crossed and they are mentioned only to show that the subject traveled a long way.